# What causes the 'Community' user to protect questions?

Tags: support, question-protection

When does a question qualify for the community or a mod to protect it from "thanks" and "me too" comments? It didn't seem to have to do with views or votes.

Comment: I believe it's just something that is done when it actually becomes a problem.

Comment: It's a rep privilege. Therefore it's the decision of any passing 15k+ user whether a question should be protected, and their criteria are up to them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two ways:

1. A mod or [15k+ user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) manually selects a question for protection (this is an uncommon occurrence, and is not done lightly)
2. When a mod deletes or converts an answer (usually because they were intended as comments) by a <20 rep user, and there are two other such deleted answers on the question (for a total of 3), the question will automatically protect itself -- "Protected by Community".

Because you do not have 10k rep, you aren't able to see the deleted answers these questions have in common.